# Why do we follow the same rules for solving equations when solving inequalities?

Tags: inequality

I was surprised when I saw that you need to solve an inequality the same way for solving an equation for one exception: If you multiply or divide by a negative number, you need to reverse the inequality symbol like this: $${-5b\over -5}\lt{7.5\over -5}$$which evaluates to $$b\gt-1.5$$This *needs* to happen or nothing will be true if you don't reverse the symbol.  Anyway, let's cut to the chase.  Now, why do we need to follow the same rules for solving equations when solving inequaties?  An example is this:$$10b+5\ge105$$$$10b+5-5\ge105-5$$$$10b\ge100$$$${10b\over 10}\ge{100\over 10}$$$$b\ge10$$Why should we follow the rules of solving equations this way?  I hear a *big* commotion of answers out there!  Now I'll just check the solution for the first inequality: Let's substitute $b$ for $-1$:$${-5(0)\over -5}\lt{7.5\over -5}$$$${0\over -5}\lt{7.5\over -5}$$I think I have to reverse the symbol here.  Now it's time to simplify:$$0\gt-1.5$$The solution checks.  Have fun answering!

Comment: That first deduction is so wrong, it's hard to know where to begin.

Comment: Since $\frac{-5b}{-5}=b$ and $\frac{7.5}{-5} = -1.5$, that inequality just means $b<-1.5$.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the first one.

Comment: No, you didn't. You still have the inequality in the wrong direction. Now, if $-5b<7.5$ then you can conclude $b>-1.5$. But that is not what you said.

Comment: Okay, I figured out what was wrong and changed it.

Comment: No, it is still wrong.

Comment: If $u<v$ and $u=x$ and $v=y$ then $x<y$. Since $\frac{-5b}{-b}=b$ and $\frac{-7.5}{-5}=1.5$, $$\frac{-5b}{-b}<\frac{-7.5}{-5}$ means $b<1.5$, not $b>1.5$.

Comment: How should I fix this...

Comment: You could start with the inequality $-5b<-7.5$, which implies $b>1.5$.

Comment: Oh, yeah.  All I had to do was to reverse the symbol at the end after checking my solution.  It _did_ work!

Comment: You may also note we can't subtract inequalities, the way you would equations. Unless you couch it as multiplication by $-1$ and addition, provided at that stage the inequalities have the same sense ($\le, \, \ge$ etc. ).

Comment: I didn't want to change the inequalities, all right?  I cancelled out the fives in the second inequality so I can isolate the variable by dividing by the coefficient on each side.

Comment: It looks like I've proved you wrong in your second comment in a row here, Thomas Andrews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean for $x<y$? Mathematicians first tend to define "positive." The positive numbers have a number of properties, but the big ones are:

- For any positive $x,y$, $xy$ and $x+y$ are positive.
- $0$ is not positive.
- If $x$ is not zero, then either $x$ or $-x$ is positive.

If we define $x<y$ as "$y-x$ is positive." We can deduce the properties of inequalities based on this definition and the properties of the positives.

On the other hand, equations $x=y$ can be rewritten as "y-x is zero."

So a lot of the things we can do with equations we can do with inequalities because of the first bullet item above. It's trickier with inequalities, because if $x=0$ then $ax=0$ for any $a$, but if $x$ is positive, we only know that $ax$ is positive if $a$ is positive.